# Unwanted xmlns attribute in all Xml noded

Tags: c#-4.0, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml, nodes, xml-namespaces

I am copying nodes of one XDocument element to another new XDocument using below code:

```
        #region Namespace...

        XNamespace xsd = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
        XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
        XNamespace schemaLocation = XNamespace.Get("tv:noNamespaceSchemaLocation");

        #endregion Namespace...

        var doc = new XDocument();

        doc.Add(new XElement("tv",
             new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsd", xsd),
             new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi),
             new XAttribute(xsi + "schemaLocation", schemaLocation))
            );

        doc.Root.Add(new XElement("channel",
           new XAttribute("id", channelId),
           new XAttribute("name", channel),
                new XElement("display-name", channel))
           );


        var xmlPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PastXmlFolderPath"] + "Day" + x + @"\" + channel + suffix + ".xml";


        var xDoc2 = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);

        doc.Root.Add(xDoc2.Descendants()
               .DescendantNodes()
               .OfType<XElement>()
               .Where(n => n.Name.LocalName.Equals("programme")));
```

However the duplicate xml document has an unwanted attribute xmlns="tv:noNamespaceSchemaLocation" in all the nodes which was not in original xml.

**Current Output:**

```
<programme channel="W9" start="2016201002000 +0100" stop="2016201010000 +0100" xmlns="tv:noNamespaceSchemaLocation">
     <length units="minutes">40</length>
     <title>Intelligence *2013</title>
     <category>Série</category>
</programme>
```

**Desired Output:**

```
<programme channel="W9" start="2016201002000 +0100" stop="2016201010000 +0100">
     <length units="minutes">40</length>
     <title>Intelligence *2013</title>
     <category>Série</category>
</programme>
```

How do I get rid of this extra namespae in all the nodes "xmlns="tv:noNamespaceSchemaLocation".

Thanks

Comment: Well presumably your *input* XML file contains `programme` elements in that namespace. You're adding those elements to your document, so they're still in that namespace. Are you saying you don't actually want to add the elements from the other document? It would help if you'd provide a [mcve] including the desired output.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for replying. I have updated the OP with current output & desired output. The source xml nodes does not contain this namespace but the xml descriptor (top line) of source has this "<tv xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="tv:noNamespaceSchemaLocation">"

Comment: Then those elements *are* in that namespace, because `xmnls=...` sets the default for descendant elements. So if you want to actually copy the element into the new document, it *should* have that namespace. If you're really trying to copy a "sort of" eqiuvalent set of elements, that's a different matter. We're still missing a [mcve] though, which would help in terms of being able to present an answer.